# Which lifecycle hook to edit dom in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a very basic angular2 web application. I would like to know the right place/hook where I could add code to edit the DOM.

When I tried placing it in **ngAfterViewInit** I see the following error

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
```

The only way I found to make it work it to wrap my code in a timeout like so

```
setTimeout(_ => {
   .... code comes here ...
})
```

This does not seem like the right way to do it. Any thoughts?

Component JS Code

```
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit {

  techImageSize = "100"

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    setTimeout(_ => {
      var w = $("[data-container=tech-images]").width();
      this.techImageSize = Math.floor(w / 4) + "";
    })
  }

}
```

Relevant Template Code:

```
<div class="col-md-5" data-container="tech-images">
  <div class="" style='overflow: auto'>
    <tech-image image='heroku-logo.png' [size]="techImageSize"></tech-image>
    <tech-image image='surge-logo.svg' [size]="techImageSize"></tech-image>
    <tech-image image='swift-logo.png' [size]="techImageSize"></tech-image>
    <tech-image image='heroku-logo.png' [size]="techImageSize"></tech-image>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and your code is... ?

Comment: @smnbbrv I updated the post, thanks!

Comment: Could we see your component template HTML as well? At least for the relevant `data-container="tech-images"` element. I'm guessing that one of its dimensions is being set to `this.techImageSize`, but that happens during a change detection cycle.

Comment: Do take a look now :)

Comment: @PrakashRaman, JackKoppa explained pretty well why you get this error, and this is why setTimeout is necessary - to avoid messing with change detection. Apart from that, please note that any direct manipulations with the DOM (particularly using jQuery) are strongly discouraged in Angular.

Comment: @PrakashRaman, anything unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46525222/2545680)?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. I assume that you're using `techImageSize` in the component template. The `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hooks is triggered after the DOM is checked. Then you update it to

```
this.techImageSize = Math.floor(w / 4) + "";
```

so during next validation stage Angular detects the difference in the value of  `techImageSize` and throws the error.

Depending on the template of the component you may need to wait for `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook and in this case using async update through timeout is the correct approach. However, usually, you can access the DOM in any hooks since DOM is already rendered when change detection start and hooks are triggered.

You can read more in:

- [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)
- [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)
- [The essential difference between Constructor and ngOnInit in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular-c9930c209a42)

Comment: I see, thanks. Reading through the posts. In this case, when is the right time to update the DOM. Or how can I update it before it gets checked?

Comment: @PrakashRaman, I updated the answer. See paragraph starting with `Depending...`